# Visualize us counties using shiny and plotly

Tags: shiny, plotly

I want to create a simple shiny app like below. But instead of states I want to visualize by US county. You can find dataset below. Any ideas? I could accept even something else than plotly but I want the mouse hover ability.

```
# Grab air/water quality data from the EPA
url = "https://data.cdc.gov/api/views/cjae-szjv/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD"
dat <- read.csv(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# Colnames tolower
names(dat) <- tolower(names(dat))
dat$countyname <- tolower(dat$countyname)
# Wide data set, subset only what we need.
county_dat <- subset(dat, measureid == "296", 
                 select = c("countyfips","statename", "countyname", "value", "unitname"))
# Rename columns to make for a clean df merge later.
colnames(county_dat) <- c("fips", "state", "county_name", "value", "unitname")
# Have to add leading zeos to any FIPS code that's less than 5 digits long to get a good match.
# I'm cheating by using C code. sprintf will work as well.
county_dat$fips <- formatC(county_dat$fips, width = 5, format = "d", flag = "0")
# Convert full state names to abbreviations for a clean df merge later.
county_dat$state <- state.abb[match(county_dat$state,state.name)]

    library(shiny)
    library(plotly)

    ui <- fluidPage(
      plotlyOutput("plot"),
      verbatimTextOutput("click")
    )

    server <- function(input, output, session) {

      output$plot <- renderPlotly({
        # specify some map projection/options
        g <- list(
          scope = 'usa',
          projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
          lakecolor = toRGB('white')
        )
        plot_ly(z = state.area, text = state.name, locations = state.abb,
                type = 'choropleth', locationmode = 'USA-states') %>%
          layout(geo = g)
      })

      output$click <- renderPrint({
        d <- event_data("plotly_click")
        if (is.null(d)) "Click on a state to view event data" else d
      })

    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this with `ggplotly`, `geom_polygon` and `maps::map_data`. It takes a lot of time to process tough, so you might want to save the resulting plot as a HTML using `saveWidget`. The code has been adapted from the documentation of `?geom_polygon`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)

states <- map_data("county")
colordata <- data.frame(
  subregion = unique(states$subregion),
  ## replace color with a vector of air quality measurements
  color = rnorm(length(unique(states$subregion))) 
)

choro <- merge(states, colordata, sort = FALSE, by = "subregion")
choro <- choro[order(choro$order), ]

p <- ggplot(choro, aes(long, lat)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(group = group, fill = color))

p_ly <- ggplotly(p)

# display the plot
p_ly

# save the plot widget
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(p_ly, "plot.html")
```

### Update

You can also just use

```
map('county', fill = TRUE, col = sample.int(20,1777,TRUE))
```

to get this plot

[image]

Comment: head(foo)
   County State County_ID        EQI    air_EQI  water_EQI   land_EQI
1 Autauga    AL      1001  0.0041379  0.9553846 -1.1097280 -0.7065906

Comment: Actually this is how my dataset looks like the other was a large dataset just for the example.I want to visualize by County and use EQI as "z"

Comment: You can see here what im trying to achieve but( not just for california but the whole country) https://plot.ly/r/county-level-choropleth/#add-countylevel-data